# regular expression for Wikitext to HTML

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am Tryting to show wiki text in HTML in my app(Using cakephp). I use this expression for `<h4>,<h5>,<h6>`

```
'/^==== (.*) ====$/'
    =>  '<h4>\1</h4>',
    '/^===== (.*) =====$/'
    =>  '<h5>\1</h5>',
    '/^====== (.*) ======$/'
    => '<h6>\1</h6>',
```

`[http://www.wikipedia.org Wikipedia]` will be shown as `<ahref="www.wikipedia.org">Wikipedia </a>`

`[5|Text]` will show like `<a href="http://fillpage/5/page_slug">Text</a>`

`[[6#HeadingB|Text ]]` will shown as `<ahref="http://fillpage/6/page_slug#HeadingB>Text</a>`

`[[6#HeadingB]]` will shown as 
`<a href="http://fillpage/5/page_slug">PageTitle</a>`

`[media:631|Description|Position]` will shown as 
`<img class="position" src="http://fullpath/lang_code/631.jpg">`Description

I wan't to know how to make such regex for links(exactly like Wikipedia shows.) how to make it done. And how to match space b/w two brackets for links.

Comment: I will bet you a nickel there is a library out there that will do this for you, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Not for MediaWiki syntax, actually. The parser it uses is insane enough that the only implementation is the PHP one in MW itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match `\[(.*?) +(.*)\]`

and replace with : $2

or if you're using preg in php

Go for this:

`'/\[(.*?) +(.*)]$/'`

and accept them with backslash like so : `'<a href="\1">\2</a>'` within an array as the value to the pattern above as a key.

That was up for wikipedia. You can go to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and use the pattern references on the right column.

Hope it helps.